# RegEx for non-numeric + allow only single "." for input validation

Tags: javascript, regex, validation

Kindly help me out for below requirement.

1. Replace non-numeric from input
2. but allow only one digit for floating constants.

Here is my requirement

```
var a = "$150.00"
```

Now when user tab out on this input value; it should remain as it is. But it is getting as `$15000`

This is regex I am using.

```
this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]/i,'').split('').reverse().join('');
```

Validation is happening on keydown event.

Answer (score 2):

Add an optional period into the regex.

```
this.value.split('').reverse().join('').replace(/[\D]\.?[\D]/i,'').split('').reverse().join('');
```